# Is there a TCP proxy adapter which converts non-persistent to persistent connections?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, proxy, network-programming

I would like client **A** to establish non persistent connections (send FIN packets, No more data from sender) to a server **B** which accepts only persistent connections (no FIN packets).

Is there any TCP Proxy **P** that can be in the middle and work as an adapter - filter

```
A ---non-persistent(FIN)---> P ---persistent(no FIN)---> B
```

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: what do you even mean by non-persistant TCP connection? In TCP a connection is either connected or it isn't.  Or are you talking about HTTP persistent connections, which is nothing to do with TCP, but with HTTP framing allowing for multiple requests on the same TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you @Adrien for your feedback. I reedit my question and make it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean an *HTTP* proxy?

Comment: @EJP, No HTTP, it's a socket programming .

Comment: So like a plug proxy where the back end connection stays up regardless of the client disconnecting?  I don't know of any software which does this, mostly servers will tear down everything when the client disconnects, otherwise they consume more and more resources.  What happens to the back end server when it's disconnected?  A server that can't handle disconnects I have to say is extremely lame.

Answer (score 1):

If persistence is supported and the exact semantics depend on the application layer protocol spoken. This means there is no general transport layer (TCP) proxy which can translate any kind of non-persistent connections to persistent connections. But it is possible to create such a thing for example for HTTP.